# Attaching an image to a img element after loading it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I am making a navigation bar with a list of items, each one having an image and a text associated. I use react-virtualized list so it wouldn't load all items basically I needed to work with this:

- Each item title need to be loaded asynchronously from IndexedDB. It isn't a real request (I use pouchdb), but it takes a few ms
- Each item subheader needs to be loaded asyncronously, by using PouchDB allDocs then `length` property to show how many children it has (I use [docuri](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docuri) for ids)
- Each item has an image to display, stored as attachements
- There is a dozen item displayed at the same time, so I cannot load all image at once because this would hurt the performance when loading, so I need to use a queue so only one element is loaded at a time.
- I'd rather not use redux for this part since those components are used everywhere in the UI

I decided to go for something like this:

```
export default abstract class LibraryItemComponent extends React.Component {
  protected image: HTMLImageElement;

  abstract loadImage (id: string, img: HTMLImageElement): void;

  abstract loadItem (id: string): void;

  abstract unloadItem (): void;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadItem(this.props.id);
    this.loadImage(this.props.id, this.image);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps: LibraryItemComponentProps) {
    if (nextProps.id !== this.props.id) {
      if (nextProps.id) {
        this.loadItem(nextProps.id);
        this.loadImage(nextProps.id, this.image);
      }
    }
  }
  render () 


    return <div >
      <div className="item-image"><img src={BLANK_IMAGE} ref={(ref) => this.image = ref} data-doc-id={this.props.id} /></div>
      <div className="item-props">
        <div className="item-name">
          {this.renderHeader()}
        </div>
        <div className="item-subtitle">
          {this.renderSubtitle()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
```

The `loadImage` implementation looks like this:

```
  loadImage(id: string, img: HTMLImageElement): void {
    MediaManager.getInstance().load(id, this.image);
  }
```

The `load` from `MediaManager` is something like:

```
  load (docId: string, target: HTMLImageElement, watch = true): Promise<Blob> {
    target.src = BLANK_IMAGE;
    return this.queue.add(() => {
      if (!this.shouldAttach(docId, target)) {
        return Promise.resolve(new Blob());
      }
      return this.database.getAttachment(docId, size).catch(...).then((res: Blob) => {
        if (!this.shouldAttach(docId, target)) {
          return Promise.resolve(new Blob());
        }
        return this.attach(res, target, oldSrc);
      });
    });
  }

 attach (blob: Blob, target: HTMLImageElement, oldSrc: string): Promise<Blob> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (!target || oldSrc !== target.src) {
        return resolve(blob);
      }
      target.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      target.addEventListener('load', () => {
        resolve(blob);
      });
    });
  }
```

As you can see the load function first loads the blob, and then attaches the image to the target. Once the image is loaded and displayed, the promise is resolved and the promise queue may go on, loading the next requested image.

However, if the image receives another id (so it now displays another item title) while it still loading the old image, this old image will still get (needlessly) loaded AND displayed, only to disappear once the new image gets loaded.

So I added an attribute to the `img` element, `data-doc-id` which contains the current document id. The load and attach function then cancel themselves thanks to `shouldAttach`

```
 shouldAttach (docId: string, target: HTMLImageElement) {
    if (!document.contains(target)) { // element has been removed from dom
      return false;
    }

    const attr = target.getAttribute('data-doc-id');
    if (attr && attr !== docId) { // we already changed document
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

The problem is that when the component receives a new document, `componentWillReceiveProps` gets called but if the queue is empty, the `load` function from ImageManager gets called immediately, but the `data-doc-id` hasn't been updated yet (because componentWillReceiveProps) so it will cancel itself. Thus, **the image does not get displayed**. How can I fix this?

The first and easy idea would be something like

```
 this.image.setAttribute('data-doc-id', newDocId);
```

But I'd like to avoid as much as possible direct DOM mutations, given that in my experience it may causes instability with React.

I was thinking about creating a map with `docId: imageObjectURL` but a queue implementation would be hard a tedious to implement, and I would lose reusability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to ref a div and appendChild a `<img>` on it. This would allow you to the remove the child when its id changes. This also allows you to fully load the image before appending it to the div. React doesn't care, because the div isn't a concern of React.